# Insertar <i> tag para añadir un icono dentro de un botón generado de forma dinámica con JS

Tags: javascript

quiero añadir un tag  dentro de un button que genero de forma dinámica con javascript, ya que uso este tag para añadir iconos haciendo uso de la librería de iconos de Google. He estado buscando información y no localizo nada relacionado ¿Alguien me lo puede explicar?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Aquí muestro la generación del botón

```
  if(t.remainTime <= 1 || deadline == '') {
    clearInterval(timerUpdate);
    //el.innerHTML = finalMessage;
    var myButton = document.createElement("input");
    myButton.type = "button";
    myButton.classList.add("btn");
    myButton.classList.add("deep-orange");
    myButton.classList.add("lighten-1");
    el.innerHTML = '';
    el.appendChild(myButton);
  }
```

-------Edito

He probado lo siguiente:

```
 if(t.remainTime <= 1 || deadline == '') {
    clearInterval(timerUpdate);
    //el.innerHTML = finalMessage;
    var myButton = document.createElement("input");
    myButton.type = "button";
    myButton.classList.add("btn");
    myButton.classList.add("deep-orange");
    myButton.classList.add("lighten-1");
    var myicon = document.createElement("i");
    myicon.innerHTML = 'add';
    myicon.classList.add("material-icons");
    myButton.appendChild(myicon);
    el.innerHTML = '';
    el.appendChild(myButton);
 }
```

La idea sería metér en el botón algo similar a esto:

```
<i class="material-icons">add</i>
```

Comment: En tu código tienes el ejemplo de cómo crear un elemento (button) y agregarlo a otro (el). Intenta crear tu elemento `i` y agregarlo a `button` siguiendo lo que ya tienes. Si algo falla, regresa para editar la pregunta y agregar lo que intentaste y no funcionó.

Comment: @Triby hecho, muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente, eso debe funcionar. Si no, edita nuevamente tu pregunta y menciona con detalle qué es lo que está fallando, además de código que nos permita probar y reproducir el problema.